# Symfony2 resetting session lifetime clears all sessions from other project running on a server

Tags: php, symfony, session

I've been trying to maximize session lifetime in symfony2 like the below code that I've found. I have two different projects in my localhost and I need them both open and running in a browser.

```
if(isset($_POST['remember_me'])){
                $this->container->get('session')->migrate($destroy = false, 2419200);
            }else{
                $this->container->get('session')->migrate($destroy = false, 3600);
            }
```

In my config.yml on 2 projects, I have these settings:

```
framework:
    session:         
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions"
```

Both projects are working and can be open in a browser until I've added this line $this->container->get('session')->migrate($destroy = false, $lifetime) to reset the session lifetime. I thought it works great with resetting the lifetime of the session until Ive found out that it clears the sessions from the other project.

Anybody can help please..?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Save sessions to project specific directory, or move them to database.

Comment: I like to save sessions in the DB as its useful if you end up scaling to a load balanced server setup. [Heres](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html) how.